# How many apache MaxClients to use?

Tags: apache-2.2

So I have a vps running 512mb of ram and 1 vCPU, what would be the optimal amount of MaxClients (apache workers) I should run in order to get the most efficient serving of a website? Currently it's only hosting a very basic Wordpress installation.

Comment: As many as will fit in RAM without swapping out.

Comment: This depends on which MPM you are using and how much RAM each of your children/threads uses.  It also depends on what else is running on the server (such as a database) and how much RAM the other things use.  Could you add that information to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Find average memory of apache process divide it with your RAM allocated for apache.

Since you have 512 Mb RAM,allocate 256-300 Mb for apache and rest for normal operation(if this is dedicated for webserver and no other services are running).

Let say if your average process size is 5Mb then u can have upto 51 max clients(255/5).

Dont over allocate maxclient value it can lead to swapping.